# How to define default field value but not on database level?

Tags: django

[image]

I want to have default value of text field being calculated for user.
Eg. Now year=2020, so User choice would be 2020 and 2021 in dropdown field.
But in next year(2021) I want to have 2021 and 2022 values to be only possibile choices.

Field is defined like this in models.py:

```
year = models.CharField(default=default_year(), max_length=4, choices=year_choices(), )
```

where:

```
def default_year():
        return str(datetime.now().year)

def year_choices():
    current_year = datetime.now().year
    years = []
    years.append([str(current_year), str(current_year)])
    years.append([str(current_year + 1), str(current_year + 1)])
    return tuple(years)
```

So it works for now, but because of migration it will not change in next year, right?

Whats causing trouble is migration:

```
migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='movie',
            name='year',
            field=models.CharField(choices=[['2020', '2020'], ['2021', '2021']], default='2020', max_length=4),
        ),
```

How to avoid appying hardcoded values in migration file, or set calculted values in form in other way?

Comment: best to do it on the frontend side. use js or jquery

Comment: The best way is to use custom forms everywhere